# unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, serialization

I am storing data in mysql table by serialize method, now I want to print all data So I wrote mysql query and trying to unserialize because data is in serialize format but unserialize showing error.

Error:

```
unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Query to fetch all records

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from($table);
$result=$this->db->get()->result();
$unserialize_list=unserialize($result);
```

Comment: Not sure if using serialized data is the best option for data storage.  JSON may be a better option.

Comment: Your serialized data is in one column of the result set, you need to unserialize that, not the array of columns returned from your query.

Comment: @NigelRen previously I stored  in json but json is too bad with associative array and I confirmed same on stackoverflow post

Comment: If you do `select * from table` you get some sort of a recordset. Even if there is only one column and one row. And you pass that recordset into unserialze, which expects only a single string. Take the respective column from the respective row and pass it into unserialze.

Comment: You get an associative array from your response. Just use smth like $var=$result['columnname'], then work with $var

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$result` variable contains a multi-dimensional array.

Assuming that some of the data in the table is serialized, and since you have not posted your table schema, here is a sample table that I hope matches your use case:

```
Id | Data
-------------------
1  | a:2:{s:4:"Name";s:5:"Test1";s:8:"Location";s:9:"Somewhere";}
2  | a:2:{s:4:"Name";s:5:"Test2";s:8:"Location";s:14:"Somewhere Else";}
3  | a:2:{s:4:"Name";s:5:"Test3";s:8:"Location";s:18:"Somewhere Else Too";}
```

Running this code:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from($table);
$result=$this->db->get()->result();
$unserialize_list=unserialize($result);
```

Will result in an array of objects, one for each line in your table, like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Id] => 1
            [Data] => a:2:{s:4:"Name";s:5:"Test1";s:8:"Location";s:9:"Somewhere";}
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Id] => 2
            [Data] => a:2:{s:4:"Name";s:5:"Test2";s:8:"Location";s:14:"Somewhere Else";}
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Id] => 2
            [Data] => a:2:{s:4:"Name";s:5:"Test3";s:8:"Location";s:18:"Somewhere Else Too";}
        )

)
```

You need to run the following code in order to access the unserialized data:

```
foreach ($result as $line) {
    $unserializedData = unserialize($line->Data);
    // Use the unserialized data as needed...
    print_r($unserializedData);
}
```